# The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database

Tags: sql, reporting

I got the following error when trying to use SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services manager:

The report server cannot decrypt the symmetric key that is used to access sensitive or encrypted data in a report server database. You must either restore a backup key or delete all encrypted content. (rsReportServerDisabled) Get Online Help
Bad Data. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090005)

I understand that I need to reset my encryption keys. But by doing so, I have to reset all connection strings and db credentials for all of my data sources.

My question is :

Since I have more than 300 reports and 5 data sources. By Reseting it will it delete the data source and I have create new one. Or remove the connection string only.

If I have to create 5 new data sources, I have to set the data source to each and every report. Isnt it?

Also can I get the connection string of all my data sources from the report server DB?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem, and deleting all encrypted content is a painful experience. It will delete your 5 data sources and the connection string /shared data sources on all 300+ of your reports. You will have to fix each report one-by-one, but there is a faster way to fix your individual reports than editing them in BIDS or ReportBuilder3.

Go to each report, click the drop down and select 'manage'
[image]

Add the shared data source and save.
[image]